# Can't debug Android crash with no application code in Crashlytic's stacktrace

Tags: android, stack-trace, crashlytics

After recent update to the app, a slew of crashes started to trickle in. As far as I confirmed no changes to the layout were made but there was a significant number of changes so we can't be sure. This is the stack trace I see in the crashlytic's logs. There is no application code.

We could not reproduce (more suitable to say "find") the crash ourselves :(

The problem seems to be isolated to OS 4.4.*

What we did do is update the compatibility library and "upgrade" to the 4.4W - API Level 20 compilation target as opposed to 4.4.2 - API Level 19

Would appreciate thoughts, advice and directions where to look for a solution.

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1010)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17367)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:382)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17367)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17367)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2174)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1315)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1512)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1199)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6383)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Are you using any hacks somewhere to modify say, the status bar, or some other system UI elements? This seems to imply that somewhere you're casting a child's `LayoutParams` to a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instance, when the child is actually a child of a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: No, we do not use any hacks. The exception itself (you are pointing out to) is clear but does not help much. We are also pretty sure we have not changed anything in our layout (xml or code) though...

Comment: Any code where you're modifying the contents of the ActionBar (other than the usual menu inflation)?

Comment: No, we don't do anything to action bar except menu injection (which was not changed)

Comment: If you're lacking a 4.4.X device to test on, could you link me to the app and I'll give it a shot?

Comment: We do have several 4.4.X devices. We are pretty sure that this crash is not consistently reproducible. If it was, we would see much more crashes. We tested on several 4.4.X devices (phones and tablets). Thank you for your proposal but I believe this would be a waste of your time :–(

Comment: Sorry to hear it. :( Those are the worst crashes to try to debug. One final suggestion would be to just grep your code for anywhere you manually set/adjust `LayoutParams` on a view and make sure nothing could be amiss.

Comment: I already did what you are proposing of course. Could not find anything "suspicious"...